# how to install a package from a zip file in WinPython?

Tags: python

I am currently using WinPython 2.7 for a project and I need to install the package SFrame which is in the following repository:

https://github.com/turi-code/SFrame

I have downloaded the zip file which is called SFrame-master.zip and installed into the directory that I am working.

After that, in Spyder I have selected the menu Tools and the option Open Command prompt and in there I went to the folder in which is the zip file>

cd directory...

and then I enter the following command:

pip install SFrame-master.zip

but the following error appears:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\myFolder\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-axu5cu-build\\setup.py'
```

and when I open a file an put:

```
import sframe
```

it does not recognize it, so the question is how can I install a package from a zip file in Python without using the github link?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `pip install -U sframe`? Why are you installing from a zip?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just want to know how to install from a zip in WinPython; sometimes I found packages on the web on zip file and I was no able to install them

Comment: Have you tried extracting the zip and then running `pip install` inside the extracted directory?

Comment: yeah and still nothing

Comment: Based on the file name, it sounds like you just downloaded the repository. That is not a valid python package; it's the source code to build it. If you want to install from an archive, try downloading the tar.gz from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SFrame). However, on Windows, I think the better option is the wheel (whl file).